How to apply circuit cutting to MCX gates?
I am working on a quantum version of a fuzzy controller (https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/9869303). This inference engine is implemented with a quantum circuit composed of X and MCX gates as in the image below. The problem is that this circuit once transpiled has a depth of more than 3000 and obviously I get uniform distributions when executing it on IBM real backends.

While looking for a solution I came across circuit cutting. Do you think this could be an appropriate approach? And how would you apply to this circuit?
EDIT:
Since I have access to ibm_brisbane, ibm_kyiv and ibm_sherbrooke, the following is the coupling map I am dealing with.


What are the coupling maps for the backends that are being transpiled to like?

@JosephGeipel Hi, I have access to ibm_brisbane, ibm-kyiv and ibm_sherbrooke. I edited the question and added a map view.
